# Determine if Explorer Window Has Focus

Tags: windows, vbscript, explorer

I am trying to write a `vbs` script which will get the directory path of the `Explorer` window that has focus (if there is one).  So far, I have this code, which will print out a list of open Explorer windows, but I have no way of knowing which one currently has focus.  Any ideas?

```
With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    For Each Wnd in .Windows
        If TypeName(Wnd.Document) = "IShellFolderViewDual3" Then
            WScript.Echo Wnd.Document.Folder.Self.Path
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  lists the properties and methods of a Shell Window object. I don't see anything that's going to help you out. If your script created all of the windows, you could probably monitor their `WindowActivate` events to keep track of which was activated last.

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible. What are you trying to achieve.. what is the end goal? Maybe there is another way to do what you want

Comment: @Jobbo I want to create a file in the active explorer directory. I created a custom button on the explorer menu (see my previous question) and am trying to find someway to get the directory from where the button was chosen. I figured if you press the button, then that window must be active.

Comment: Wow that's horrific.. Why would you want to do that when there is a right-click menu to create new files?

Comment: @Jobbo Because right-clicking, scrolling to `New |>`, pausing, scrolling to `New Text Document`, and clicking it is much slower than clicking a button to create a new text document. This is something I do frequently and it is an annoyance.  Also, I am planning to extend it to more complex files. E.g. I could click `New HTML File` and a file will be generated with pre-populated `<!doctype html><html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: I see. Your idea of pre-populated files is really easy in Linux (Nautilus) but is also possible in windows. See `http://www.techrepublic.com/article/techrepublic-tutorial-add-file-types-to-windows-new-command-menu/` However this just adds your template files to the 'new' menu. Maybe it speeds the process up a little

Comment: @Jobbo Thank you for the reference! I didn't know you could do that. Actually, your suggestion has given me an idea. I can get it working by using `SendKeys` to simulate opening the `New` menu and choosing an option.  I used `SendKeys %FWWW~T"`.  `%F` opens the `File Menu`, I had three options with a `W` accelerator key, and `New` was the 3rd one, `~` opens the menu and `T` selects a text file.